# Using UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)play {
    if (!self.mapViewController)
    {
        self.mapViewController = [[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapViewController animated:YES];
}
```

What happen is: when I pressed the play button for the first time, new view doesn't show up. When I pressed again, it crashes because the same UIViewController have been added into the stack more than once. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit:
Thank you for all of your answers. I checked the xib and I've found that I messed up the links. Fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok try this below code this is worked for me:
if current viewcontroller is not uinavigation controller try this code:

```
- (IBAction)play {
   MapViewController *mapView = [[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapViewController"    bundle:nil];
   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:mapView];
   [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}
```

(or) if currentviewcontroller is uinavigation controller try below code:

```
  - (IBAction)play {
    MapViewController *mapView = [[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapViewController"    bundle:nil];//Note:Check the mpviewcontroller xib file name as MapViewController is correct
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapViewController animated:YES];
   }
```

Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

Create the view controller in your -init merhod, then only push the view controller in -play. Make sure your view controller is designed so that the user can 'exit' from it, thus popping it from the stack, thus not generating an error for multiple openings.

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController` will do more bookkeeping than you think.
You simply need to create your controller and push it.
No need to maintain your own reference.

Also, if you name your nib `MyView.xib`, you won't need to specify it's name explicitly; it'll pick it up on initialization. From [`nibName` property docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW13):

> If the view controller class name ends with the word “Controller”, as in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the class name without the word “Controller”, as in MyView.nib.

So your code can just become:

```
- (IBAction)play {
    // Implicitly loads MapViewController.xib
    UIViewController* mapViewController = [[[MapViewController alloc] init] auotrelease];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapViewController animated:YES];
}
```

As long as Map uses `popViewController`, the `UINavigationController` will handle deallocation and ensure you don't wind up with multiple copies on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -->

```
 - (IBAction)play 
{
    mapViewController = [[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapViewController animated:YES];
    [mapViewController release];
}
```